# how to format result of Collection.find before passing to template

Tags: mongodb, meteor, handlebars.js

HTML:

```
    <div class="leaderboard">
        {{#each players}}
          {{> player}}
        {{/each}}
    </div>
    <template name="player">
      <div class="player {{selected}}">
        <span class="name">{{name}}</span>
        <span class="score">{{score}}</span>
        <span class="joindate">{{joindate}}</span>
      </div>
    </template>
```

JS:

```
Players = new Meteor.Collection("players");
if (Meteor.isClient) {
  Template.players = function () {
    return Players.find();
  };
}
if (Meteor.isServer) {
  Meteor.startup(function () {
    if (Players.find().count() === 0) {
      var names = ["Ada Lovelace",
                   "Grace Hopper",
                   "Marie Curie",
                   "Carl Friedrich Gauss",
                   "Nikola Tesla",
                   "Claude Shannon"];
      for (var i = 0; i < names.length; i++)
        Players.insert({name: names[i], 
                       score: Math.floor(Random.fraction()*10)*5,
                       joindate: new Date().getTime()
                     });
    }
  });
}
```

From the example above, I've stored joindate as a unix timestamp. How do I format the join date variable into a readable date in the result of Collection.find before returning the Template.players function.

I know that I can format the date in the insert command but my question is how to manipulate/format data in the collection.find before passing to the template.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass a [`transform` function](http://docs.meteor.com/#meteor_collection) while creating a `Collection`:

```
var Players = new Meteor.collection('players', { 
    transform: function(doc) { 
        doc.joindateStr = (new Date().getTime()).toString(); 
        return doc;
    }
});
```

And then use `joindateStr` in your Template. Or you can override `joindate` itself to be a `Date` object.

The `transform` function will be applied to all the documents returned by `find` and `findOne`. It can also be passed at the second argument to `find` or findOne` explicitly.

Comment: Thank you very much! One thing tough, you're missing return doc; in the function.

Comment: @ian Included it. Thanks!